# how to re-install python 2.7.5

Tags: linux, rhel, python

we have redhat version 7.2

and python

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5

which python
/usr/bin/python
```

we suspect that python modules or python env are not correct

so is it posible to re-install the python version - 2.7.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exact error message you have received?
Also good to check your environmental variable called "PYTHONPATH":

echo $PYTHONPATH

The PYTHONPATH defines, where Python modules are located.
It can be modified via shell profile files, as .bashrc, .bash_profile etc. depending on your user shell.